# Restarting Amazon EMR cluster

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, emr, hadoop2

I'm using Amazon EMR (Hadoop2 / AMI version:3.3.1) and I would like to change the default configuration (for example replication factor). In order for the change to take effect I need to restart the cluster and that's where my problems start.

How to do it? The script I found at `./.versions/2.4.0/sbin/stop-dfs.sh` doesn't work. The slaves file `./.versions/2.4.0/etc/hadoop/slaves` is empty anyway. There are some scripts in init.d:

`$ ls -l /etc/init.d/hadoop-*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  477 Nov  8 02:19 /etc/init.d/hadoop-datanode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  788 Nov  8 02:19 /etc/init.d/hadoop-httpfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  481 Nov  8 02:19 /etc/init.d/hadoop-jobtracker
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  477 Nov  8 02:19 /etc/init.d/hadoop-namenode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1632 Oct 27 21:12 /etc/init.d/hadoop-state-pusher-control
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  484 Nov  8 02:19 /etc/init.d/hadoop-tasktracker`

but if I for example stop the namenode something will start it again immediately. I looked for documentation and Amazon provides a 600 pages user guide but it's more how to use the cluster and not that much about maintenance.

Comment: did you find out how to do this?

Comment: What I've founded out was that I shouldn't be doing it. If you want to change cluster settings you have to do it though the "steps" during creation process.

Answer (score 1):

On `EMR 3.x.x` , it used traditional SysVInit scripts for managing services. `ls /etc/init.d/` can tell you the list of such services. You can restart a service like so,

```
sudo service hadoop-namenode restart
```

> But if I for example stop the namenode something will start it again
>   immediately.

However, EMR also has a process called `service-nanny` that monitors hadoop related services and ensure all of em' are always running.  This is the mystery process that brings it back.

So, for truly restarting a service, you would need to stop the service-nanny for a while and then restart/stop the necessary processes. Once you bring back service nanny , it will again do its job. So, you might run commands like -

```
sudo service service-nanny stop
sudo service hadoop-namenode restart
sudo service service-nanny start
```

Note that this behavior is different in 4.x.x and 5.x.x AMI's where upstart  is used to stop/start applications and service-nanny no longer brings back applications.